# Does MySQL support partial indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, relational-database

Partial indexes only include a subset of the rows of a table.

I've been able to create partial indexes in Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, and SQL Server. For example, in SQL Server I can create the index as:

```
create index ix1_case on client_case (date) 
  where status = 'pending';
```

This index is cheap since it does not include all 5 million rows of the table, but only the pending cases, that should not exceed a thousand rows.

How do I do it in MySQL?

Comment: MySQL does not support partial indexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Gordon Linoff commented, MySQL does not (yet) support partial indexes.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can create an index that behaves like a partial index by leveraging [multi-valued indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued) in a clever way.

To get the effect of:

```sql
-- Does not work in MySQL because WHERE clause not supported
CREATE INDEX staff_is_true ON auth_user (id) WHERE is_staff = 1;

SELECT id FROM auth_user WHERE is_staff = 1;
```

**You can use:**

```sql
CREATE INDEX staff_is_true ON auth_user ((CAST((CASE WHEN is_staff THEN JSON_ARRAY(1) ELSE JSON_ARRAY() END) AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)));

SELECT id FROM auth_user WHERE 1 MEMBER OF(CASE WHEN is_staff THEN JSON_ARRAY(1) ELSE JSON_ARRAY() END);
```

When I `EXPLAIN` the latter `SELECT` statement with the index present I see that ONLY the (is_staff = 1) rows are considered:

```
+-----+---------------+-----+-------+------+
| ... | key           | ... | ref   | rows |
+-----+---------------+-----+-------+------+
| ... | staff_is_true | ... | const |   20 |
+-----+---------------+-----+-------+------+
```

And if the index is NOT present I see that ALL rows are considered:

```
+-----+------+-----+-------+--------+
| ... | key  | ... | ref   | rows   |
+-----+------+-----+-------+--------+
| ... | NULL | ... | NULL  | 100000 |
+-----+------+-----+-------+--------+
```

I can prove the index is partial rather than complete by verifying that at most 1 row is considered when querying for the (is_staff = 0) case:

```
mysql> explain select id from auth_user where 0 MEMBER OF(CASE WHEN is_staff THEN JSON_ARRAY(1) ELSE JSON_ARRAY() END) ;
+---------------+-----+------+
| key           | ... | rows |
+---------------+-----+------+
| staff_is_true | ... |    1 |
+---------------+-----+------+
```

Comment: It seems that the `WHERE` clause is not yet supported as of MySQL 8.0.30. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2UZw24b_).

Comment: Indeed. That's why I suggest the multi-valued index workaround with JSON_ARRAY.

Answer (score 0):

Queries that need the index you suggest may benefit from

```
INDEX(`status`, `date`)
```